# Tensorflow on Elastic Beanstalk and Django

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        sentences = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
        import tensorflow_hub as hub
        embed = hub.Module('/tmp/module')
        embeddings = embed(sentences)
```

This is from my views.py file in my django app.
the execution fails at the import and shows the following error.

End of script output before headers: wsgi.py child pid 29409 exit
signal Segmentation fault (11)

While it works fine on my local machine.
I am currently using a t3 medium instance. Any tips on how to fix this ?

Comment: Could it be that it is looking for some GPU support and fails? Also tensorflow is a resource heavy tool. Not sure if t3.medium would have enough ram for it. Have you tried checking ram usage?

Comment: Ram usage is normal. If I ssh into the instance, and activate the same virtualenv I am able to import tf, whereas the import fails inside the django view. Is there a memory setting I am missing out ?

Comment: Posting this here in case someone else runs into the same issue. So I tried bigger instances, running it manually on the instance and the segfault issue would randomly pop up. So far I have been able to avoid the issue by importing tf as the first import in my script. I dont see how this is solving the issue but so far importing it first has kept the issue from happening agin. Will update if I run into this again and spend more time on it.